# conversion Nsstring

Tags: iphone, type-conversion

Hi all guys ,I am new in objective c and I need help, I read from my `xml`
file and I want convert my `NSString` to `bool` and `NSString` to `date` and
`Nsstring` to `long`

```
NSArray *names = [partyMember elementsForName:@"price"];
        if (names.count > 0) {
            GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [names objectAtIndex:0];
            price = firstName.stringValue;
        } else continue;

        NSArray *names1 = [partyMember elementsForName:@"date"];
        if (names1.count > 0) {
            GDataXMLElement *firstName1 = (GDataXMLElement *) [names1 objectAtIndex:0];
            date = firstName1.stringValue;

    NSArray *names1 = [partyMember elementsForName:@"test"];
        if (names1.count > 0) {
            GDataXMLElement *firstName1 = (GDataXMLElement *) [names1 objectAtIndex:0];
            test = firstName1.stringValue;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the BOOL
A string is NO if its either `nil` or length 0. Otherwise its YES.

NSDateFormatter's `dateFromString` will convert strings to dates. You set it up with a c style formatter.

For the long use `longValue` as in long long myval = [mystring longLongValue];

NSString has several converters 
`– doubleValue
– floatValue
– intValue
– integerValue
– longLongValue
– boolValue`

Use as required.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please first look at Apple's documentation. It is very thorough. In the [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) on `NSString`, you can see there is a `boolValue` method and a `longLongValue` method. You can read the specifics in the documentation, but those will handle your bool and long cases.

As for converting a date, there are many stackoverflow questions on that topic, this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate) should answer your question.

I'm usually not one to say RTFM, but in this case the information was very easily found with a couple quick searches.

Comment: I too was tempted to say RTFM. Maybe more a discussion for meta.stackoverflow but I wonder if it would be possible to get a review/warning for questions which come up with a certain weight of similars

Answer (score 0):

To convert `NSString` to `BOOL` use below method.

```
BOOL boolValue = [myString boolValue];
```

For converting to long use [`longLongValue:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/longLongValue) method of NSString.

For `NSString` to `NSDate` , use below as reference code.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-07-13";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: NSString * string=@"2011-07-05T10:26:13.91+02:00"; haw i do to format this strind

Answer (score 0):

NSString itself has functions to get bool and float values.

See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

To get date, u need to look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).