# Converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert NSString of a date to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate)

I need some help with formatting dates.

I have a string in the format `2011-10-05`. How do i convert this `NSString` into `NSDate` object.

Furthermore I want to retrieve the day from the corresponding NSDate object.

I know I have to use a dateFormatter but I am not able to work around it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Converting+NSString+to+NSDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-10-05"];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day     = [dateComponents day];
NSLog(@"day: %d", day);
```

NSLog output:

```
date: 2011-10-05 04:00:00 +0000
day: 5
```