# NSDate from NSString like HH:mm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a strings - time, start, end: format "hh:mm"

for example, "21:00". 
I need compare -  "time" falls between the Start and End
if End < Start, for example ("21:10" "10:00") should be considered as: from 'Start' to 'End' the next day.

I can't convert NSSTring like @"23:00" to NSDate, and then I need to compare... :(

Thanks for advice ;)

Comment: This is what NSDateFormatter is for.  Or you can use NSCalendar.  Of course, for your "next day" logic you need to actually do some programming.

Comment: Looks right to me.  What's your timezone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSString of a date to an NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string of type `HH:mm` into an `NSDate`. If `endDate` is *smaller* than `startDate`, then add a day to it.

```
NSString *dateString = @"23:00";
NSString *startString = @"21:00";
NSString *endString = @"10:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startString];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endString];
if ([endDate compare:startDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    endDate = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:24*3600];
}

if ([startDate compare:date] == NSOrderedAscending && [date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"Date %@ is in the interval [%@, %@]", dateString, startString, endString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Date %@ is not in the interval [%@, %@]", dateString, startString, endString);
}
```

PS. I am assuming ARC is used here.

Comment: I have thought about it before, but your example helps me to realize it ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: yeap, it's correct, but I added     [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
to get proper NSDate from formatter