# Sorting NSArray which contain array of dictionaries - Sort as per "Date" key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, sorting

*I have the following NSArray which contains a dictionary at each index , here is the content, just providing first 3 records-*

```
[
            {

                "postDate": "4/11/2011 2:03:33 PM",
                "imageLink": "",
                "eventLink": "www.google.com"
            },
            {

                "postDate": "6/16/2011 1:42:45 PM",
                "imageLink": "",
                "eventLink": "www.google.com"
            },
            {

                "postDate": "9/21/2011 10:22:34 AM",
                "imageLink": "",
                "eventLink": "www.google.com"
            }
]
```

**NOTE:-** `postDate` is just a NSString it is not coming in NSDate type, but I have to perform sort on basis of this key.

My task is to sort the array as per the "postDate" key , means the whole array will be **sorted in order by date** (ascending/descending).

I have used the following code, but didn't help as `arr` is storing the all the data from  `arrEventsData` but sorting is not happening:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate"  ascending:YES];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[arrEventsData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]]mutableCopy];
```

Any idea or solution will help.

Thanks

Comment: Those aren't dates, they are strings.

Comment: Yes, they are strings.I cannot change it as it is coming from backend.

Comment: You cannot change it?

Comment: I mean I can change it manually just by updating postDate key value to Nsdate format in my program, but cannot change it from server end.

Comment: Well that sounds like a step in the right direction...

Comment: What is happening to this data afterwards? Are you creating objects out of it? Or just using it like it is?

Comment: I want to sort the Original array and store it in other array, so that I can display events as per date range @JasperPol

Comment: @Droppy I have already tried by updating the postDate key value to NSDate type, but sortedArrayUsingDescriptors doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss a"];

NSArray *sortedByDates = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1[@"postDate"]];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2[@"postDate"]];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
NSLog(@"Sorted Array : %@",sortedByDates);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
        NSDate *d1 = [self stringToDate:obj1[@"postDate"]];
        NSDate *d2 = [self stringToDate:obj2[@"postDate"]];
        return [d1 compare:d2];
    }];
```

For the "stringToDate" method, however you want to implement that, see another SO answer here: [Convert NSString of a date to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate)

Edit: As @Droppy has pointed out, it would really be best to parse the string into a NSDate as soon as the data arrives from the server. That prevents expensive repeated conversion in sorting, and is probably all around more useful anyway.

Comment: I'm sure that will work, but the repeated conversion of string to date will make it expensive.

Comment: (even more so if you follow the code you linked and create a new `NSDateFormatter` each time).

Comment: Sure. But it depends on how many records you have whether or not that would cause a problem. If it did, there's numerous ways to cache the conversion. Not doing that for him either ;)

Comment: ... like converting the data to a custom object as soon as it's parsed, for example?

Comment: Yes that's one option. Spend as  much time as you need to make the stringToDate method as fast and as efficient as you need. I wouldn't bother at all if I process, say, 10 records at a time. If theres 100, maybe. If there's 1000, sure.

Comment: @Droppy that's a good idea - maybe. It really depends on the problem space which we don't know anything about. I didn't want to go too overboard with this solution. Just to show how to sort an array of dicts.

Comment: Well the OP has already hit one issue by keeping the data in the form it was delivered in (via JSON I guess).  People do not seem to appreciate the time saved by creating a custom Model object for their data.  Oh well, their loss...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78886/discussion-between-n13-and-droppy).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create `NSDate` objects from those `NSString`'s to make the `compare` work

Create a static NSDateFormatter as they are expensive to create:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {

        static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; //Set correct format here
        });

        NSDate *first = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[a objectForKey:@"postDate"]];
        NSDate *second = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[b objectForKey:@"postDate"]];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```